# dkim-milter appears not to be signing my emails correctly

Tags: email, spam, dkim

I have a VPS that I had a fresh install of CentOS 6 on it and then I installed virtualmin on it and we've been great for a few months. I've been hosting a handful of domains from there and on one of the domains in particular, I'm going to need to send out email (and not go to spam).

The domain I'm trying to fix is toyotasupraclassifieds.com

I have both my hosting DNS and server DNS mirrored (to the best that I can). My domains are using the nameservers on the hosting DNS.

I created an TXT record for my SPF that was generated from the SPF Wizard on Microsoft on my hosting platform. I also followed the instructions provided in the Virtualmin documentation to install a domain key and the installation ran without any error and I followed the directions correctly. I copied that domain key and created a TXT record on my hosting DNS as well.

So I've been testing my stuff to see if it goes straight to spam and it does..... so I looked online and ran a couple checks.

- Kitterman's spf validator says half the time this says I don't have an SPF record and the other half it says its fine.
- MailRadars DKIM check says

  ```
  Domain-Key Status: NOT PASSED, The message does have have a domain key
  ```

  but I have the following header displayed below.....

  ```
  DKIM-Signature: my domain key
  ```
- Brandon Checkets DKIM test says a couple things.

  ```
  DomainKeys Information:
  Message does not contain a DomainKeys Signature
  ```

  but then it says this further down....

  ```
  DKIM Information: DKIM Signature Message contains this DKIM Signature: DKIM-Signature: ...... *my dkim *

  Validating Signature result = invalid Details: public key: OpenSSL error: bad base64 decode
  ```

  SPF records pass on this test as well.
- On protodaves DKIM check, half the time it says there are no records, but if I keep hitting the check button, it will popup with the record that says it can't parse the value of the DKIM record so it doesn't know if it's working or not.

I'm honestly not sure what to try at this point. I stopped/restarted dkim-milter and restarted postfix to no avail. I have an SSL on that IP (and domain in fact) but I still get that error. I updated all the packages I could so I'm as up to date as possible. Can someone help direct me on what steps I should take for things to check or what to do next? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I fixed it on my own. dkim-milter is a useless piece of deprecated garbage :D. I did a `yum remove dkim-milter` and then a quick `yum install opendkim`. I followed the directions in [this article for setting up OpenDKIM](http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/installing-opendkim-rpm-via-yum-with-postfix-or-sendmail-for-rhel-centos-fedora/) and got er done. It started signing my emails and I was a happy guy. I did have to change the setting in my conf file in tip 2 on that article.

> Tip 2: If OpenDKIM is starting properly and logging to your mail log,
>   but your outgoing mail isn’t getting signed, the first thing to check
>   is whether the default operating mode is still set to the default
>   verification only (v) instead of sign and verify (sv) in
>   /etc/opendkim.conf. Change the Mode to sv, restart OpenDKIM, and try
>   sending your test message again.